# TDCH with oozie is failing while connecting to Hive

Tags: hadoop, teradata, oozie

I am trying to execute data import from Teradata to Hive using TDCH 0.15. The import is working fine while issuing a CLI command on namenode but failing with below error when integrated with oozie (using Java node). Is it because of missing library?

```
2016-10-10 16:36:02,743 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database d0_edw1_ato, returning NoSuchObjectException
2016-10-10 16:36:02,750 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: InvalidObjectException(message:d0_edw1_ato)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1451)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.create_table_with_environment_context(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2056)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:663)
    at com.teradata.connector.hive.utils.HiveUtils.createHiveTable(HiveUtils.java:979)
    at com.teradata.connector.hive.processor.HiveOutputProcessor.outputPostProcessor(HiveOutputProcessor.java:258)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:162)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorImportTool.run(ConnectorImportTool.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorImportTool.main(ConnectorImportTool.java:813)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:56)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

Comment: Share your properties file and workflow.

Comment: `Failed to get database d0_edw1_ato, returning NoSuchObjectException` this happens when you have either old jar or multiple version of the same jar and wrong jar is loaded.